# Interrupt For loop with button selection

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I'm currently implementing an image sorter that moves a photo to a directory based on button press.
When the directory is given through cmd, the prompt stops the for loop for each photo however with the button press the for loop continues until it loads the last photo. Is there a way to interrupt the loop at the first image and wait for a button press to continue?

Code:

```
for file in os.listdir(SourceList.source):
    photo = Image.open(SourceList.source+file).resize((750,500), Image.ANTIALIAS)
    img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(photo)
    panel = Label(self, image = img)
    panel.image = img
    panel.grid(row=0, rowspan=2, column=1, columnspan=2, sticky=N)
    #panel.pack(side = "top", fill = "none")

 #Moves image based on button pressed
def MoveIm(num):
    if num == 1:    #If button X clicked, set dest
        dest = 'C:\\Dest\\' 
    shutil.move(SourceList.source+file, dest)

button1 = Button(self, text = "Dest",command = partial(MoveIm, 1))
button1.grid(row=0, column=0, pady=50, padx=50, sticky=N)
```

Comment: you want to ask the choice before you move the image..if YES move if  NO don't move..??

Comment: No I want the image to move straight away on button press and then the program will present the next image. At the moment it skips straight to the last image when i run it. I need a way to make it stop at each image until i click the button

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Store your files in a list, display the first file then update the image to the next file when you press the button

```
def MoveIm(num):
    if num == 1:    #If button X clicked, set dest
        dest = 'C:\\Dest\\' 
    shutil.move(SourceList.source+file, dest)
    #update image shown at this point
```

Comment: Thanks for this, I'm new to programming in general so let me see if I understand what you mean. 
In the for loop all  I would do is store all the files in a list somehow.
Then use the same code I have to diplay the images but from this new list.
Then add code in MoveIm to progress through the list?

Comment: Yep thats exactly it. So just use that code to set the first image in your list as the display image, then every time you run your MoveIm function you update that displayed image to the next image in the list. You also need to check that you have a next image - theres lots of ways to do this, iterators would be the cleanest way imo, but if you're new to programming it will probably make more sense to you at this point to keep a counter that you increment each time you get a new image. Before you get the next image, check that the counter is a valid index (i.e. less than len(list_of_files))

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your code it seems to be intend issue .
Call your method/function inside the loop. your method/function is being called post loop is over so it is taking the last file in directory. Though I am not aware of complete structure of your code but below is jut a try...

```py
# Moves image based on button pressed
def MoveIm(num):
    if num == 1:    # If button X clicked, set dest
        dest = 'C:\\Dest\\' 
    shutil.move(SourceList.source+file, dest)


for file in os.listdir(SourceList.source):
    photo = Image.open(SourceList.source+file).resize((750,500), Image.ANTIALIAS)
    img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(photo)
    panel = Label(self, image = img)
    panel.image = img
    panel.grid(row=0, rowspan=2, column=1, columnspan=2, sticky=N)
    #panel.pack(side = "top", fill = "none")

    # To be called inside the loop 
    button1 = Button(self, text = "Dest",command = partial(MoveIm, 1))
    button1.grid(row=0, column=0, pady=50, padx=50, sticky=N)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create an iterator on the file list returned by `os.listdir(...)`:

```
imagelist = iter(os.listdir(SourceList.source))
```

Then create a function to show the image:

```
def NextImage():
  global fullname
  fname = next(imagelist, None)
  fullname = os.path.join(SourceList.source, fname) if fname else None
  if fullname:
    photo = Image.open(fullname).resize((750, 500), Image.ANTIALIAS)
    img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(photo)
    # update panel instead of creating new one
    panel.config(image=img)
  else:
    # create a blank image
    photo = Image.new('RGB', (750, 500), 'white')
    img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(photo)
    panel.config(text='No more image', font=('Arial', 64, 'bold'), image=img, compound=tk.CENTER)
  panel.image = img
```

and modify `MoveIm()` function to move the current image and show next image:

```
def MoveIm():
  if fullname:
    # and move the image
    shutil.move(fullname, 'C:\\Dest\\')
    # show next image
    NextImage()
```

Below is an example:

```
import tkinter as tk
from PIL import Image, ImageTk
import os
import shutil

# simulate your SourceList object
class SourceList:
  source = '/path/to/images'

def NextImage():
  global fullname
  fname = next(imagelist, None)
  fullname = os.path.join(SourceList.source, fname) if fname else None
  if fullname:
    photo = Image.open(fullname).resize((750, 500), Image.ANTIALIAS)
    img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(photo)
    # update panel instead of creating new one
    panel.config(image=img)
  else:
    # create a blank image
    photo = Image.new('RGB', (750, 500), 'white')
    img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(photo)
    panel.config(text='No more image', font=('Arial', 64, 'bold'), image=img, compound=tk.CENTER)
  panel.image = img

def MoveIm():
  if fullname:
    # and move the image
    shutil.move(fullname, 'C:\\Dest\\')
    # show next image
    NextImage()

root = tk.Tk()

panel = tk.Label(root)
panel.pack()

button1 = tk.Button(root, text='Dest', command=MoveIm)
button1.pack()

imagelist = iter(os.listdir(SourceList.source))
NextImage() # show the first image

root.mainloop()
```